# import data of grid in pdf without using any third party dll

Tags: asp.net, pdf, export

i am developing an app in which i want to give support of export data in to pdf if user want then he can get the grid data into pdf .
i have tried many methods but not working.
its working by using itextsharp third party dll but not directly .
Using :c# ,asp.net

```
protected void btnExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f,10f,10f,0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End(); 
}
```

Comment: Similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11107084/298573

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it by using isharptext if you want to do it with code than you'll have to write parser .

Answer (score 0):

Pdf stands for portable document format. Since it is a standard format you will have to put your data in that format only. other wise it will be a corrupt file and wont be prased by pdf readers. You will have to use 3rd party tools or roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a decent PDF parser is a huge amount of work (we are talking years) so most people find it far more cost-effective so license IText or a similar library.