# How i get data of datagridview in pdf in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to take data from a Table in Excel and automatically fill in multiple & fillable PDF forms using a macro.

[image]

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/about and http://stackoverflow.com/faq to learn about the types of questions you can ask here. To use this site, you should show an attempt at the problem, not ask others to do the work for you. Perhaps you can post some code attempts and the errors you are getting and we can help.

Comment: Sorry i i am a new user sorry

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103771/itextsharp-to-print-a-gridview

Comment: Thax and sorry dont mint i am a new sorry

Comment: do you want to download the pdf? or send it across internet?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article which explains how to convert datagridview to PDF and excel files

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28269/Exporting-a-DataGridView-to-an-Excel-PDF-image-fil

Here is what I have done recently in one of my projects:

```
public void ExportToPdf(DataTable ExDataTable) //Datatable 
  {
    //Here set page size as A4

    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);

  try
   {
      PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
      pdfDoc.Open();

       //Set Font Properties for PDF File
       Font fnt = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 12);
       DataTable dt = ExDataTable;

        if (dt != null)
        {

            PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
            PdfPCell PdfPCell = null;

            //Here we create PDF file tables

            for (int rows = 0; rows < dt.Rows.Count; rows++)
            {
                if (rows == 0)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
                    {
                        PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Columns[column].ColumnName.ToString(), fnt)));
                        PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
                    }
                }
                for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
                {
                    PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Rows[rows][column].ToString(), fnt)));
                    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
                }
            }

            // Finally Add pdf table to the document 
            pdfDoc.Add(PdfTable);
        }

        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        //Set default file Name as current datetime
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".pdf");

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfDoc);

        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanxx but this article i cannt understand

Comment: Which part of it haven't you understood?

Comment: I am new programmer i cannt understand heavy programming like this.

Comment: @SaimaMaheen- I have updated with my solution and let me know still if you have any issues with it.

Comment: hy thanx bosss i try it later now i off my computer u where from?

Comment: you can check my profile for further help.

Comment: did u add any  spl libraries for using pdf? if so plz say what it is.. @coder