# how to convert DataGridView to pdf in utf8

Tags: c#, datagridview, itext

I am using `iTextSharp.dll` for converting `dataGridView` to `pdf` in c# It does not make a `pdf` as `utf8` so i have 2 the problems there:

the `utf8` problem and it also put column from left to right how can i made them from right to left

Here's the code:

```
 private void pictureBox10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fdialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = fdialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            string file = fdialog.SelectedPath;
            //Creating iTextSharp Table from the DataTable data
            PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridViewX2.ColumnCount);
            pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
            pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
            pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

            //Adding Header row
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridViewX2.Columns)
            {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
                //cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
                pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
            }

            //Adding DataRow
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewX2.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
                }
            }

            //Exporting to PDF
            string folderPath = file + "\\PDFs\\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
            }
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(folderPath + "DataGridViewExport.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: Find a Persian support dll instead

Comment: @AlexJolig  thank you for replaying. you mean there is not any way to save that as UTF8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-ASPNet-GridView-Arabic-Persian-or-Urdu-Language-Characters-to-PDF-using-iTextSharp.aspx) for exporting `GridView` to PDF using `ITextSharp`:

```
protected void btnExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\fonts\Arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);

    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable table = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(GridView1.Columns.Count);
    int[] widths = new int[GridView1.Columns.Count];
    for (int x = 0; x < GridView1.Columns.Count; x++)
    {
        widths[x] = (int)GridView1.Columns[x].ItemStyle.Width.Value;
        string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[x].Text);

        //Set Font and Font Color
        iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
        font.Color = new Color(GridView1.HeaderStyle.ForeColor);
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase(12, cellText, font));

        //Set Header Row BackGround Color
        cell.BackgroundColor = new Color(GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor);

        //Important for Arabic, Persian or Urdu Text
        cell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
        table.AddCell(cell);
    }
    table.SetWidths(widths);

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);

                //Set Font and Font Color
                iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
                font.Color = new Color(GridView1.RowStyle.ForeColor);
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase(12, cellText, font));

                //Set Color of row
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    //Set Row BackGround Color
                    cell.BackgroundColor = new Color(GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor);
                }

                //Important for Arabic, Persian or Urdu Text
                cell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }
        }
    }

    //Create the PDF Document
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    pdfDoc.Add(table);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}
```

Note that:

> The iTextSharp DLL supplied with the code sample of this article has
>   been modified to allow GridView Styles, Colors and Formatting. Thus if
>   you use any other copy of iTextSharp the GridView Styles, Colors and
>   Formatting won’t be rendered in the exported PDF.

**Edit**

As a second solution, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107084/2263683), there's a [link](http://hasheminezhad.com/sites/default/files/hasheminezhad.com/GridToPdf-lib.zip) which might help you in your problem.

> [This GridView exporting library](http://hasheminezhad.com/sites/default/files/hasheminezhad.com/GridToPdf-lib.zip) supports RTL

**Edit 2**

Third solution mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10336531/2263683) might help you as well

> When dealing with Unicode characters and iTextSharp there's a couple
>   of things you need to take care of. The first one you did already and
>   that's getting a font that supports your characters. The second thing
>   is that you want to actually register the font with iTextSharp so that
>   its aware of it.
>
> ```
> //Path to our font
> string arialuniTff = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts),
> "ARIALUNI.TTF");
> //Register the font with iTextSharp
> iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(arialuniTff);
> ```
>
> Now that we have a font we need to create a `StyleSheet` object that
>   tells iTextSharp when and how to use it.
>
> ```
> //Create a new stylesheet
> iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
> //Set the default body font to our registered font's internal name
> ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Arial Unicode MS");
> ```
>
> The one non-HTML part that you also need to do is set a special
>   `encoding` parameter. This encoding is specific to iTextSharp and in
>   your case you want it to be `Identity-H`. If you don't set this then
>   it default to `Cp1252` (`WINANSI`).
>
> ```
> //Set the default encoding to support Unicode characters
> ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);
> ```
>
> Lastly, we need to pass our stylesheet to the `ParseToList` method:
>
> ```
> //Parse our HTML using the stylesheet created above
> List<IElement> list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(stringBuilder.ToString()), ST);
> ```
>
> Putting that all together, from open to close you'd have:
>
> ```
> doc.Open();
>
> //Sample HTML
> StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
> stringBuilder.Append(@"<p>This is a test: <strong>α,β</strong></p>");
>
> //Path to our font
> string arialuniTff = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts),
> "ARIALUNI.TTF");
> //Register the font with iTextSharp
> iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(arialuniTff);
>
> //Create a new stylesheet
> iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
> //Set the default body font to our registered font's internal name
> ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Arial Unicode MS");
> //Set the default encoding to support Unicode characters
> ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);
>
> //Parse our HTML using the stylesheet created above
> List<IElement> list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(stringBuilder.ToString()), ST);
>
> //Loop through each element, don't bother wrapping in P tags
> foreach (var element in list) {
>     doc.Add(element);
> }
>
> doc.Close();
> ```
>
> **EDIT**
>
> In your comment you show HTML that specifies an override font.
>   iTextSharp does not spider the system for fonts and its HTML parser
>   doesn't use font fallback techniques. Any fonts specified in HTML/CSS
>   must be manually registered.
>
> ```
> string lucidaTff = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts),
> "l_10646.ttf");
> iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(lucidaTff);
> ```